# Random bad Unicode character in https chunked response

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

**Context**: When using the `https` module in Node to retrieve JSON data from, say, a REST webservice, the boilerplate code is generally something like:

```js
let body = '';
let parsed = null;
const req = https.request(options, res => {
  res.on('data', chunk => {
    body += chunk;
  })

  res.on('end', function() {
    parsed = JSON.parse(body);
  })
})
```

That is, we start with an empty `body` string, and append the incoming chunk (a `Buffer`) to it, until we get to the end of the response, where we can safely parse it as JSON.

Now, I have a case where sometimes, the parsed response contains bad Unicode characters in the middle of the (big) JSON object instead of regular characters, e.g.:

The string I should get: `sans ingrédients`

The string I get: `sans ingr��dients`

So, instead of a regular `é` (`0xC3 0xA9`) , I get a pair of replacement characters (`0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`).

This is pretty random — and it doesn't come from the webservice in itself since it never occurs when calling it directly.

I have an *intuition* that the `body += chunk` could be the problem, when a chunk happens to cut right after the first byte of the `é`.

This is quite far-fetched, but my understanding is that *maybe*, `body += chunk` is trying to convert `chunk` to a String before appending to `body`, finds this lonely `0xC3` at the end of the buffer, doesn't understand it for some reason, replaces it with `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`, and same same for the next chunk that would start with a lonely `0xA9` that would receive the same treatment.

**But** I can't find any documentation or any warning that we shouldn't use `+=` directly for that, so I'm not sure. Nor that the chunk size would change.

For now, I have changed my code to:

```js
let body = []
let parsed = null
res.on('data', (chunk) => {
  body.push(chunk)
})

res.on('end', () => {
  body = Buffer.concat(body).toString()
  parsed = JSON.parse(body)
})
```

... and I'm waiting to see if I have the problem again.

But I want to understand — **Am I saying non-sense?** Are both snippets equivalent ?
Thanks a lot !